# How many bitcoin clones are out there?

Tags: alternatives, protocol

How many bitcoin clones are out there?

I mean people changing the name, the hashing algorithm and a few more parameters and creating a new coin that just keeps on copying bitcoin's source code in eternity?

Is there a list of those somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

My favourite today is [mapofcoins.com](http://mapofcoins.com)

You can browse alt-coins list here: [coinwik.org](http://coinwik.org/List_of_all_DCs)

You can compare coins here: [coinplorer.com/Hardware/CurrenciesComparison](http://coinplorer.com/Hardware/CurrenciesComparison)

There is forum, [cryptocointalk](http://cryptocointalk.com/forum/358-cryptocoins-cryptocurrencies/)

See, here [coingen.bluematt.me](http://coingen.bluematt.me/status.html) and +10 hidden market places with constructors.

**You can't find full list of all alt-coins. It doesn't exist.**

Number of alt-coins grows so fast. Probably, every day there are appear 10-20 alt-coins. This is unstoppable trend. In the Jan of 2015 there will be more than 1000 alt-coins in one hundred percent.

---

Edit:

See, another one constructor [COIN NUKE | COIN CREATION SERVICE | +EVERYTHING FOR YOU COIN +ESCROW +TOOLS](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=565417.0)

Comment: Great resources +1

Answer (score 2):

[A list of relevant cryptocurrencies and their differences](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List%5fof%5falternative%5fcryptocurrencies) can be found on the wiki. Also (almost) every new altcoin starts with [a thread on Bitcointalk](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=159.0), where all necessary information should be stated in an announcement. See also [this article about alternative chains on the wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Alternative%5fchain).

Comment: Are all these bitcoin clones? I mean, copied and modified from the original repository? +1

Answer (score 0):

Creating a coin is so easy that it would be impossible to list them; people could create a coin and set up nodes with their friends, without talking about it online.